# Error: Target container is not a DOM element react /react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm making a gallery using react redux and database for firebase. 
I'm having this error.. 
"Error: Target container is not a DOM element" 
Could anyone help me how to fix this?

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./components/redux/reducer";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Check if id root exists on your index template

Comment: Yes, you should have a file like `public/index.html` with `<div id="root"></div>` in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is most likely that your script is executed before `#root` element created. Either move script tag to be after `#root` element in html or execute `ReactDOM.render` in the callback for "DOMContentLoaded" event.